# Is there any way for a user to see PHP?

Tags: php, html

If I have a php code on my website is there any way for a user to view it? I ask because I'm using the Pear mail package (I might change before I upload my website), and it requires my email and password be in the code for it to use. Is this a potential security risk, or is there no way for the user to see this code anyways?

While we are at it, is there a good guide for hackers on how to exploit security risks(specifically SQL injections and similar methods)? It would be useful when checking my site's security, if I had a full list of all the common things that hackers try, and explanations for how to do them.

Comment: Only through mis-configuration of the web server. May be a good idea to hedge against even that by placing passwords in config files outside of the document root.

Comment: wow, downvote party... what's going on here?

Comment: *"it would be useful... if I had a full list of common things hackers try"* .... I suggest reading https://www.owasp.org/ -- it's pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping a password in a PHP program file is extremely common practice.

As long as you've named all your files with a `.php` extension, and your server is configured to process `.php` files as PHP code, then you shouldn't have any problems.

Don't use a `.inc` extension or anything like that, because yes, that might expose your code.

Also, it's generally a good idea to place as much of your PHP code as possible outside of the web-accessible areas. Only your base PHP file that is actually loaded on startup should be web accessible. All your includes and libraries should be safely stashed away somewhere else where they can be included, but can't be read directly.

Answer (score -2):

This function will cover it:

[highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)

Comment: Right answer to the wrong question?

Comment: Read the question, not only the title.

Comment: True, my bad, got mistaken by question title "Is there any way for a user to see PHP?" which sounds more like showing PHP code on the site.